# MATLAB band-stop filter design for room reverberation?

Tags: matlab, filter-design, dsp-core, speech-processing, acoustics

I took acoustic measurements of a room using sine swept method, and I also used Pioneer sc-37 to obtain more accurate data. 
I used RoomEQ wizard software and measured the impulse response of the room, and got a long list of coefficients. and the Pioneer helped me to get the Q factor, center frequency, and attenuation.

I`m in need of some help on how to start the filter design using the data obtained.

those are the results I got

frequency

[image]

[image]

impulse response

Pioneer

[image]

[image]

[image]

I appreciate all comments and suggestions.

Comment: You did not really specify what you're trying to achieve by the filter design. Equalize the room impulse response, i.e. dereverberation? Why a band-stop filter?

Comment: sorry i was not clear, i wanna do some reverberation cancellation/supression. three band-stop filters (including a notch filter) for echo supression. and eventually i`m implementing those filter on an FPGA DE2 board.